# Android Binding Lib

Tags: android, binding

I am using the Android Binding Lib, after several hours of troubleshooting i'm starting to give up, maybe someone can help me figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

It all compiles fine, auto generated classes are created, I can run the app, however the bound fields don't seem to pick up their respected values in the view model.

I've updated Gradle:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0-beta2'
```

and added:

```
    dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```

In my activity I added the layout element:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<data>
    <import type="android.view.View"/>
    <variable
        name="vm"
        type="com.client.SiteActivityViewModel" />
</data>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/app_bg"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:visibility="@{vm.isOnShift ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}">
    <EditText
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:id="@+id/newEventBodyField"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:hint="@{vm.testText2}"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColorHint="@color/app_textColor"
        android:textColor="@color/app_textColorEmpasise"
        android:background="@android:color/white"/>
</RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

I set up my VM:

```
package com.client;
public class SiteActivityViewModel extends BaseObservable {
private boolean isOnShift = false;

public final String testText2 = "ballalalal";

@Bindable
public boolean getIsOnShift(){
    return isOnShift;
}
public void setIsOnShift(boolean value){
    isOnShift = value;
    notifyPropertyChanged(com.client.BR.isOnShift);
}
}
```

Finally I hook up the view to VM:

```
package com.client;

public class SiteActivity extends Activity {
private SiteActivityViewModel vm;
private ActivitySiteBinding binding;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_site);
    vm = new SiteActivityViewModel();
    binding.setVm(vm);

    vm.setSiteId(siteId);




    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_site);

    .....
   }
```

Comment: While i'm at it i should also note that following the official document(http://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html) didn't work for me. When i tried using 1.5.0-alpha1 as the doc suggest it didn't work. Looking around the net i found other people using gradle:1.5.0-beta2, that worked. Lastly, if you're goggling around you will find a lot of blog posts using earlier versions of gradle with a bunch of other modifications to gradle. Those are no longer needed as long as you're using 1.5.0-beta2 (or presumably higher version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I guess I just had to break it down and walk away from it a little bit. Turns out I found the issue.

I'm going to post this here in case someone else runs into the same problem.

The problem is with the order of calls in the activity. I first have to call the super class onCreate methode and set the view before I use the binding:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_site);

    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_site);
    vm = new SiteActivityViewModel();
    binding.setVm(vm);

    vm.setSiteId(siteId);

    .....
}
```